# XpsDocument ignores my height settings

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, preview, xpsdocument

I am facing a problem when I try to declare a PageHeight on an XPS Document.

My code so far looks like this:

```
private FixedDocumentSequence GetDocument(DocumentPaginator paginator)
{
    FixedDocumentSequence document = null;

    string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    File.Delete(tempFileName);

    using (var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(tempFileName, FileAccess.ReadWrite, CompressionOption.NotCompressed))
    {
        var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);

        var printTicket = new PrintTicket
        {
            PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4, paginator.PageSize.Width, paginator.PageSize.Height),
            PageBorderless = PageBorderless.Borderless,
            PageMediaType = PageMediaType.None,
        };

        writer.Write(paginator, printTicket);

        //paginator.PageSize.Height = 1122
        var d = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

        //d.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height = 1056
        document = d;
    }

    return document;
}
```

The Problem is that I am declaring a PageSize Height of 1122 which I am getting from this code:

```
var pd = new PrintDialog();
var sz = new Size(pd.PrintableAreaWidth, pd.PrintableAreaHeight);
```

but when I look into the property

```
d.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height
```

I can see that the Height is **1056**, this height happens to be the Height of the NorthAmericanLetter Page format height, I am already specifying a specific printTicket with an explicit PageMediaSize what else could be wrong?

**Edit:**

Here is my edited code, but this give the same result:

```
private FixedDocumentSequence GetDocument(DocumentPaginator paginator)
{
    FixedDocumentSequence document = null;

    string oldTempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    File.Delete(oldTempFileName);

    XpsDocument oldXpsDocument;
    using (oldXpsDocument = new XpsDocument(oldTempFileName, FileAccess.ReadWrite, CompressionOption.NotCompressed))
    {
        var writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(oldXpsDocument);

        var printTicket = new PrintTicket
        {
            PageMediaSize = new PageMediaSize(PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4, paginator.PageSize.Width, paginator.PageSize.Height),
            PageBorderless = PageBorderless.Borderless,
            PageMediaType = PageMediaType.None,
        };

        writer.Write(paginator, printTicket);
    }

    //string newTempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    //File.Delete(newTempFileName);

    using (var newXpsDocument = new XpsDocument(oldTempFileName, FileAccess.Read, CompressionOption.NotCompressed))
    {
        var d = newXpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
        document = d;
    }


    return document;
}
```

I looked into the file that got created with the first using block and I still can see that the height of the pages is 1056, output of the 1.fpage file:

```
<FixedPage 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06/resourcedictionary-key"
xml:lang="und" 
Width="816" Height="1056">
<FixedPage.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="b0" StartPoint="33,0" EndPoint="33,23" ColorInterpolationMode="SRgbLinearInterpolation" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Pad">
```

**Edit2:**

Found the a solution for my problem.
In my DocumentPaginator I had to override the GetPage Method and there I return a new DocumentPage(visual), this constructor has an overload that lets me set the PageSize only if I set it there its setting the PageSizes correctly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.documentpage(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597306(v=vs.110).aspx

My previous code:

```
public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
{
    // create page element (PageTemplate is a custom usercontrol that can hold content)
    var page = new PageTemplate(this, pageNumber + 1);

    // arrange the elements on the page
    page.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, PageSize.Width, PageSize.Height));

    // return new document page
    return new DocumentPage(page);
}
```

Now with the second contructor:

```
public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
{
    // create page element (PageTemplate is a custom usercontrol that can hold content)
    var page = new PageTemplate(this, pageNumber + 1);

    // arrange the elements on the page
    page.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, PageSize.Width, PageSize.Height));

    // return new document page
    return new DocumentPage(page, PageSize, new Rect(0, 0, 10, 10), new Rect());
}
```

Comment: I used to not have to do this with my application while I was running on Win7 as a 32-bit application.  I'm now at Win8.1 and my printing started getting goofy--printing landscaping, but result was printed portrait.  I ended up back at this post, used the overloaded constructor and now my results are as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: @Netscape No problem. - Had to lol as I saw that you are the one who answered to the question, happy to see that you could profit from my experience.

Comment: Thanks. You saved my life!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're expecting the `xpsDocument` to have the same dimensions of the file that you created.

When you create an `XpsDocument`, its going to have a default `FixedDocumentSequence`.  Since you're creating an XpsDocument, and not opening one, you're getting the default fixed document sequence, which is why you are seeing `1056` as the height--default that is the default.

However, if you look at the code example at the bottom of [FixedDocumentSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.fixeddocumentsequence(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see `LoadDocumentViewer`, where it replaces an old `XpsDocument` with a new one.

When you call `writer.Write(paginator, printTicket);` it will write an `XpsDocument` to the file you specified using the `PrintTicket` you provided.  Now you need to create an `XpsDocument` using that file path, and when you open it, you can then get the `FixedDocumentSequence` of that document and the sizes with match the `PrintTicket` properties.  So in pseudo-code, you should do this:

```
string fileName = ...
using Create XpsDocument at fileName 
    Create XpsDocumentWriter
    Create and setup PrintTicket
    Write to the file using your DocumentPaginator and PrintTicket
using Create XpsDocument reading from fileName
    document = opened XpsDocument GetFixedDocumentSequence()
```

**Edit:**

Good find in your last edit.  I printed an XPS document using MS Word with the A4 sized setting and all the pages come up as 1056 x 816 also.  I then created an XPS document using the A3 size and that comes up as 1587.36 x 1122.56.  There is clearly something going on internally that we cannot see; my guess is that since the page sizes are similar in dimension, it just uses the 1056 x 816 dimensions?  Who really knows... I would suggest filing a bug report to Microsoft.

In the meantime, maybe try to change `d.DocumentPaginator.PageSize` or even `d.PrintTicket` objects and try to get the page size to change that way.  If there is a way to enumerate the `FixedPage`'s you could change their settings manually too.

Comment: @RandRandom Added an edited... I think you've found something rather interesting.